# When is ubuntuforums.org going to be back up?

Tags: ubuntu-forums

Just wondering if anyone knows when ubuntuforums will be up and running again?

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific moment in time, not useful for future visitors once the site is up again or when the site is down later for other reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check here  [Update on status regarding re-opening the forums](http://ubuntu-discourse.org/t/update-on-status-regarding-re-opening-the-forums/754/10)

Answer (score 0):

They are reinstating the forums now, but it could take some time.  So probably around two or three days I'd imagine if they don't run into any issues along the way.